# How to install melpa in emacs?

Tags: emacs, emacs23, melpa

I need to install MELPA into my emacs 23.3 version. I have googled for the ways to install it but couldn't find/understand any of them.

Can anyone please help me with installing MELPA. I am using ubuntu 12.04

I need MELPA to install OmniSharp which will help for autocompletion in C#

Comment: You should upgrade to Emacs 24.3

Comment: For years, to get around unhelpful sysadmins I was installing emacs from source in my home directory so that I could run the version I wanted ... or run it at all.   It's easy; but you need a C compiler.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MELPA is actually just a repository of emacs packages. The emacs package manager has been included in emacs since version 24. For 23.3 you first need to get a compatible version of `package.el` (there is one [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs.git;a=blob_plain;hb=ba08b24186711eaeb3748f3d1f23e2c2d9ed0d09;f=lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el)).

After putting `package.el` in your `load-path`, you then need to add MELPA to the list of repositories:

```
(require 'package)
;; Any add to list for package-archives (to add marmalade or melpa) goes here
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
    '("MELPA" .
      "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

From the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA#toc11).

To then install OmniSharp, first refresh the package archive with `M-x package-refresh-contents`, then you can use `M-x package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `omnisharp`.

Comment: Where do I type that code to add MELPA to the list of repositories?

Comment: That goes in your `.emacs`

Comment: @Sammi3 I put it in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`